# How I can make the user exit window by window in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, window, screen, fxml

In other words, how can I make it so that the window or screen that they are on is the only screen that they can interact with. For example, if the user wants to exit from the screen but then wants to go to another screen, well then they will have to exit from the exit window first before they can do anything else. A better example is when you open multiple windows in Windows and try to exit from another screen than the one you're on, it will make a beeping noise indicating that you can't do that. Something similar to that is what I'm trying to achieve

**It's important to note that my program consists of java code, FXML and a little bit of CSS**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a frame to block all other frames from receiving events, use a modal `Dialog`.

Comment: You mean, make the `Stage` modal, I assume.